# What's happening with values when I'm passing value from color pin to scalar pin?

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to recreate color ramp node in ue5, so I need to understand what's happening when I'm passing values from texture output pin to color ramp's factor pin. It's just can't be a color because factor is scalar value, so what is it?

Comment: This is the mean of the color component (RGB) values.

Comment: @lemon  it's luminance, not average: $v = 0.2126r + 0.7152g + 0.0722b$

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, thank you, I did not know that (of course...). and pff.. I had upvoted this answer in the past...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady yes, but I want to clarify, is the formula v=0.2126r+0.7152g+0.0722b working for all cases with colors?

Comment: @Сергей not sure what kind of cases you have in mind, to my knowledge, yes, it always works and in the linked question you can see a test case proving that.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady ok, thank you very much for your help.